# Select Case search options

Tags: vbscript

I have an ASP query form that among other things includes a text box which allows the user to enter some text which can be searched for in a database.  Unfortunately, the search only returns a result when there is a match for the exact string that was entered.  Is there a way to change this so as to return a result for partial matches as well, or if what's in the DB includes all or part of the search string?

The code is below and the Case in question is the one titled "Nam".  Note that I have sort of gotten around this issue by adding an asterix wild card feature, but I'd really just prefer to avoid using the asterixes altogether. I chose to leave the extra code for the wildcards out so as not to complicate things.

```
Select Case strOption
    Case "Nam" 
    strSelect = strSelect & " Nam='" & UCase(strNam) & "'"

    Case "Location" 
    strSelect = strSelect & " Location='" & UCase(strLocation) & "'"

    Case "Typ"
    strSelect = strSelect & " Typ='" & UCase(strTyp) & "'"

    Case "Season"
    strSelect = strSelect & " Season='" & UCase(strSeason) & "'"

    Case "Duration"
    strSelect = strSelect & " Duration='" & UCase(strDuration) & "'"

    Case "Yr"
    strSelect = strSelect & " Yr='" & UCase(strYr) & "'"
End Select
```

Comment: Maybe `strSelect = strSelect & " Nam like '%" & UCase(strNam) & "%'"`

Comment: That did it!  Wow...so simple.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's more about `SQL` than `VBScript`. According the [Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174986.aspx) docs, any of *comparison* and *logical* operators return a Boolean data type with a value of `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `UNKNOWN`. More important could be reading  about *building* a [search condition (a combination of one or more predicates)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx) using operators in question; in brief:

- `=` (equal to) is the operator used to test the *equality* between two expressions;
- `LIKE` indicates that the subsequent character string is to be used with pattern matching and returns `TRUE` if the operand matches a pattern [(more on valid syntax, escaping etc.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx); a pattern can include the following valid **wildcard characters**:

  - `%` Any string of zero or more characters;
  - `_` (underscore) Any single character;
  - `[]` Any single character within the specified range (`[a-f]`) or set (`[abcdef]`);
  - `[^]` Any single character not within the specified range (`[^a-f]`) or set (`[^abcdef]`).

Thus, you could formulate a predicate on `Nam` in your search condition (in terms of VBScript) as follows:

```
strSelect = strSelect & " Nam LIKE '%" & UCase(strNam) & "%'"
```